# Expect exits too soon

Tags: expect

I have the following bash script (script.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Remove? (y|n): " answer
echo "You answered '$answer'."
```

and I would like to drive it using expect. I have the following script (expect.exp, in the same directory):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn -noecho ./script.sh
expect "^Remove"
send "y\r"
```

but it doesn't work as expected (pun intended). The result is:

```
~/Playground$ ./expect.exp 
Remove? (y|n): ~/Playground$
```

So, the expect script somehow fails on the first 'expect "^Remove"' line and exits immediately, and the rest of script.sh does not execute. What am I doing wrong here?
I have been following the basic tutorials found online (the ones with the ftp examples). I am using expect 5.45 on Kubuntu 12.10.

**Edit**
So it changes if I add either 'interact' or 'expect eof' at the very end. But I have no idea what happens and why. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things I see:

1. `"^Remove"` is a regular expression, but by default `expect` uses glob patterns. Try

   ```
   expect -re "^Remove"
   ```
2. while developing your program, add `exp_internal 1` to the top of the script. Then expect will show you what's happening.

---

Ah, I see that expect adds special meaning to `^` beyond [Tcl's glob patterns](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/glob.htm).

> However, because expect is not line oriented, these characters (`^` and `$`) match the beginning and end of the data (as opposed to lines) currently in the expect matching buffer

So what you see is that you send `y\r` and then you expect script exits as it has nothing more to do. When your script exits, the spawned child process will be killed. Hence the need to wait for the spawned child to end first: `expect eof`

Comment: 1. According to man and the net, both regexes and globs can use anchors (^ and $).
2. the correct syntax is 'exp_internal 1' but it isn't very helpful in the case when it doesn't work, it just prints:
...
Remove? (y|n): 
expect: does "Remove? (y|n): " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "^Remove"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Remove"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Remove"
send: sending "y\r" to { exp6 }
and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

You are not matching any text after the shell script's prompt, so the buffer for your spawned process never gets printed. The script finishes, the spawned process closes, and that's the end of the story.

### Solution

Make sure you `expect` a specific response or your shell script's EOF, and then print your buffer. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn -noecho   "./script.sh"
expect "Remove" { send "y\r" }
expect EOF      { send_user $expect_out(buffer) }
```

Comment: Why do I suddenly need the 'send_user $expect_out(buffer)' part? It doesn't seem to be doing anything and the script (as I mentioned in the edit to the initial question) works with just 'expect eof'.